# How to configure time out using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:timeoutable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:timeout_in => 10.seconds
```

development.rb:

```
config.timeout_in = 10.seconds
```

devise.rb:

```
config.timeout_in = 10.seconds
```

Comment: You really need to format your code with 4 spaces

Comment: So what's the problem - what's not working?

Comment: log out is not happening after 10 sec

Comment: i couldnt understand u r reply..pls help me out

Answer (score 6):

Are you expecting the page to refresh and show you a login page again? If so, that's not how the timeoutable feature works. If you're expecting it to present you with the login page when you refresh, remove the timeout part from your model and put the following in devise.rb NOT development.rb. Don't forget to restart rails server.

```
config.timeout_in = 1.hour
```

This is all documented in the devise wiki [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki)

Also, I'm not sure about the logic behind 10 seconds?? Seems a little too short. If it's still not working, increase to (for example) five minutes and test.

Comment: No problem. Check this article out: http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable

Comment: I believe 10 seconds is just for testing

Comment: @simonmorley I am having a field named "is_logged_in". I need to set it to false on timeout. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

Also it's possible to set timeout_in option dynamically

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if self.admin? 
      1.year
    else
      2.days
    end
  end
end
```