# without using devise gem,automatic logout after x minutes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have not used devise gem for login authentication and I want to implement the automatic logout functionality if user is inactive/idle for some minutes. how to do this
Please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure time out using devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495390/how-to-configure-time-out-using-devise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Devise**

In rails, you can find an option in devise initializer file `config>initializers>devise.rb`

`config.timeout_in = 20.minutes`

here you can specify the limit after which a user session will get expired. In the above case it will expire after 20 minutes and user will be asked for credentials again.

**Without Devise**

You can simply expire the user session from `config>initializers>session_store.rb`

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 30.minutes`

So all session data will expire after 30minutes. And since you will be storing the user's logged in information in session that data will get erased. So the user will be logged out after then.

Comment: s we can do that.. if i don't use devise gem for login authentication  then how can i ale to do that

Answer (score -1):

Keeping a tiny record of data per user in the session will be applicable.
For instance:

```
{
  user_id: 1000,
  timestamp: 1588061624
}
```

Set such information in the session after user login. Then on each request, first check if last touch of the data in the session is not old enough in comparison to the desired timeout. You can validate session with something like `session timestamp + timeout period > current timestamp`.

Then renew the timestamp to the current value if the session is still valid. Otherwise, remove user session and log them out.